# Next Js Api routes in App router migration routes not found

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

[image: structure]

Im trying to call nextJs api route with the new App route feature. I always get not found Back. I made the structure like in the docu.

This is my chat.js file which never gets called? Do ive the wrong structure?

1. List item

```html
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const {message} = req.body;

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            
        res.status(200).json(reply);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({error: "An error occurred while processing the request"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like page.js, your api route has to be called route.js.

So in your example it would be like this:
api(folder)=>chat(folder)=>route.js(file)

You can read more about this in docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers).